# Update dynamic headers datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the data table **version 1.10.16**. I am trying to make a pivot table. Depending on the option selected, it shows some columns or others. But when I choose an option and then choose other headers they don't work correctly.

Like in this example:
https://codepen.io/cplaiuu/pen/oNNmeam

```
var columns, click = 0, table;

 $('#show_table').on('click', function() { 

   if(table){
     table.clear();
   }

   if(click == 0){
     columns = [{'sTitle': 'Column 1'}, {'sTitle': 'Column 2'}, {'sTitle': 'Column 3'}, {'sTitle': 'Column '}];
   }else{
     columns = [{'sTitle': 'Column 1'}, {'sTitle': 'Column 2'}];
   }  

    table = $('#example').DataTable({
          dom:  "<'row'<'col-sm-6'><'col-sm-6 button_columns' f>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-5'><'col-sm-7'p>>",
          responsive: true,
          paging: false,
          columns: columns,
          language: {
            zeroRecords: 'Empty',
            infoEmpty: 'Empty',
            search: "_INPUT_",
            searchPlaceholder: 'Search',
          },
          destroy: true
          //retrieve: true 
        });
   click++;

  });
```

If you click once it shows 4 columns but the second time you click, it would have to show only 2.

I try to destroy,clear() the datatable but without result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `table.destroy()` basically removes all the DataTables formatting, but leaves the "original" table untouched in the html.  And `table.clear()` just removes the rows, but not the headers.  So you just need to destroy the DataTable and then you need to empty the table before you rebuild it.

```
if(table){
  table.destroy();
  $('#example').empty()
}
```

Here's a working snippet:

```js
var columns, click = 0, table;

 $('#show_table').on('click', function() { 
   
   if(table){
     table.destroy();
     $('#example').empty()
   }
   
   if(click == 0){
     columns = [{'sTitle': 'Column 1'}, {'sTitle': 'Column 2'}, {'sTitle': 'Column 3'}, {'sTitle': 'Column 4'}];
   }else{
     columns = [{'sTitle': 'Column 1'}, {'sTitle': 'Column 2'}];
   }  
    table = $('#example').DataTable({
          dom:  "<'row'<'col-sm-6'><'col-sm-6 button_columns' f>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-5'><'col-sm-7'p>>",
          responsive: true,
          paging: false,
          columns: columns,
          language: {
            zeroRecords: 'Empty',
            infoEmpty: 'Empty',
            search: "_INPUT_",
            searchPlaceholder: 'Search',
          }
        });
   click++;
   
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<button id="show_table"> Show table</button>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered no-footer dataTable" id="example" style="width:100%"></table>
```

Comment: Glad I found this answer. Thank you for the explanation about destroy() and clear(). It helped me to avoid future bugs.